# How can I make sure my child Node process is starting from the correct directory?

Tags: javascript, node.js, child-process

I run Node.js processes in windows server. Some npm packages require that the node process starts from the correct directory, eg [config](https://www.npmjs.com/package/config) -- I ran into this problem initially because I made a Task Manager task to run a `.bat` file that started the node process, but if I didn't explicitly set the TaskManager task to start from the containing folder of my `package.json`, config wouldn't find the correct files to load.

So if I'm starting a node process from within another node process, through something like `require('child_process').fork`, do I still have to make sure it's being called from a specific directory? How do I do that?

Comment: `console.log(__dirname)` I guess ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `.fork()`, `.exec()` or `.spawn()` on `child_process`, they all take an options object which in turn has a `.cwd` property. For example

```
const cp = require('child_process')
const child = cp.spawn('./whatever', { cwd: '/path/to/dir' })
```

Comment: nice, cwd, `current working directory`, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you my dude.

Comment: as an aside, do you know what the cwd would be by default? Would it be the path to `./whatever`, the path to the javascript file calling `cp.spawn`, or what?

Comment: I _think_ it's the same as the parent process. Print it out in your child to test it `process.cwd()`